# How to hide PAT in js file to host it at github Pages

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-pages, github-api

I have a simple html page that connects with a js file and makes api calls to gihub api, Although it works very well in my local environment as soon as I push the repository to github my PAT(personal Authentication Token) on github expires as it is now exposed to public. And my html webpage goes down as now it is not authenticated make calls to api. How can I solve this issue I want to host my html and js file online, but there is no way I can hide the PAT as its only javascript and not nodejs so there is no dotenv. Is there any way??

I tried to change the API key to PAT as chat gpt suggested this but it expires as soon as I push to the github.

Comment: Don't make the calls from the client. Put the code that calls the API on the server.

Comment: Actually I only have to submit the html css and the js file, I used to do it on the server using node js but as project only requires client side i.e, only these files I cannot create a server to call to API

Comment: If you're making the API call from the client, there's no way to hide the key from the user. The best you can do is obfuscate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no secure way to store secrets such as a PAT in a static site, such as one hosted on GitHub Pages.  The reason is that you send all the content in the static site to the user, and the user should not have the secret.  Obfuscating it is not sufficient, since it's easy to extract.

If you want to use a PAT or other secret, then a backend server is required to do this securely, since the secrets must be stored there.

Answer (score -1):

I know it is not possible and entirely unnecessary to hide sensitive information in the web page. But in the assessment I was told to set it up and deploy a single webpage using api with only html,css and JS.

But if anybody else is having the same issue then , they can just split the token into 2 or 3 parts and then join them to create a complete token, this method will not expire the token or the api key as it will not be detected.

Again , this is not at all recommended and it is highly unnecessary as the PAT or the api key is to be refrained from public display.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review your answer to include solution for the question